# MySQL first database creation

Tags: mysql, database

I need to create a database for employees that stores information about their names, salaries, salary status, dates, and messages between the employees. At least 3 users are needed. Foreign keys and an ER diagram. Can I go about creating this database by creating tables, importing data thru code and then just create a diagram by reverse engineering. I have no clue. My main concern is whether it is enough to only use tables or is there more to it?
I'm completely new to MySQL and I hope some of you can help me out.

Comment: Sounds more like you need an application (which _might_ have a database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `phpmyadmin`, you can easily create a database and tables. or if you want to create by code you can use like,

`CREATE DATABASE databasename;`

and table will be created by like,

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
column3 datatype,
....
 );
```

Comment: thank you. But I'm more stuck on importing data than anything else

Comment: Which data do you want to import?

Comment: int, charset(40), date. It's mostly text and dates. Can i add a short biography into just one table cell?

Comment: yes, you can use varchar(255), or text(), logntext() etc for taking short biography